# Format with VBA

Tags: vba

In the code below i want to do the following:

1. On line 9 format the row height to be 25.5
2. On lines 10-12 Right justify and bold the strings being inserted.

What I have tried does not work as expected. I was thinking I could use something with the "TargetCell" however I don't want to define a target range I would like each iteration of the For to do the formatting. Am I making this to complicated? Any help on this would be great !

```
Sub Program_Population()
10    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Calc")
20    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("COST SHEET")
      Dim LastRow As Long
      Dim i As Long
      Dim rngtocopy As Range
      Dim rngFinal As Range
      Dim pwd As String

30    vStart
      '****Clear previous entries in the cost sheet for program type****
40    ws2.Range("B15:B10000").ClearContents

50    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

60    Set rngtocopy = ws1.Range("B1", ws1.Cells(LastRow, "C"))
70          Set rngFinal = ws2.Range("B15", ws2.Cells(LastRow * 4, "B"))

80   For i = 1 To rngtocopy.Rows.Count
90    rngFinal((i - 1) * 5 + 1, 1) = rngtocopy(i, 1) & Chr(10) & rngtocopy(i, 2)
100   rngFinal((i - 1) * 5 + 2, 1) = "Forecast"
110   rngFinal((i - 1) * 5 + 3, 1) = "Actual"
120   rngFinal((i - 1) * 5 + 4, 1) = "Comparison"
130  Next i
140  vExit
End Sub
```

Comment: _does not work as expected_. What is it doing that is not correct. You cannot assign values to ranges the way you are. You need to use the `.Value` property to get and set the range data. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: The code basically reads a range from another worksheet and inserts this with the code on line 9. The code from line 10,11,12 inserts the associated description then the loop starts again. I would like to do the formatting as the loop executes as opposed to manually or defining a range. The loop could execute once or a hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
132 Rows("9:9").RowHeight = 25.5  'changes row 9's cells' row height to 25.5
134 Rows("10:12").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight  'changes rows 10-12's alignment to right justify
136 Rows("10:12").Font.Bold = True  'changes rows 10-12 to bold.
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your code, showing how it solves the question - this will help others who see your answer in the future